# Launch MPI executable from within another MPI program

Tags: c++, mpi

I have two programs, 1.exe and 2.exe, that each use MPI. I want to use mpirun to launch 1.exe, which then calls 2.exe and waits for it to finish before continuing. I don't need to communicate between the programs, but only read a file generated by 2.exe and process this output. Once launched, 2.exe should use all of the processors that were allocated to 1.exe since it is just waiting. Is there a good way to call 2.exe from within 1.exe?

I've tried MPI_Comm_Spawn but it seems that I need to set up an inter-communicator between 1.exe and 2.exe in order to wait for 2.exe to finish. However, I don't have access to the source for 2.exe to set up this communicator.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I just filed a similar questions with no answers so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678943/parallel-run-of-executable-within-mpi-in-c

Comment: Not a very elegant solution but I ended up just reading a file that is written by the program being called. I just sleep for a short time, read the file, then exit if it finds a line saying the program has ended. I would like something a little most robust like waitpid but I haven't been able to get anything like that to work with mpi.

Comment: won't it be a problem if you have in total more MPI processes running than actual number of cores? even if some of them are just sleeping and waiting till there is that line in the file?

Comment: The child just shares processors with the parent so it shouldn't be an issue if the parent is sleeping. There is going to be some conflict when the parent is reading the file, but that shouldn't be too bad if it sleeps for a long time compared to the time taken to read and process the file. In practice it does work, but like I said, I would prefer I better solution if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but say mpirun has launched n instances of 1.exe, each instance could spawn one instance of 2.exe asking it to do the job (via command line parameters, environment variables or any other mechanism 2.exe normally use to know what to do), this instance will use the processor allocated to the instance of 1.exe.

Then 1.exe has just to wait for 2.exe to finish, e.g. using **waitpid** : http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait or monitoring the file generated by 2.exe.

The important thing is that 1.exe is not active so will not consume its resource but will let 2.exe use it fully.

Comment: can one chosen instance of "1" run "2" in parallel and let it use all the processors?