# parallel run of executable within MPI in C++

Tags: c++, mpi

i have been using MPI for a while, but i'm not experienced. So 
i'm here to ask an advice on general structure of the following implementation. 
Say, I have the main C++ file with

```
MPI_Init(&narg,&arg);
int me,nprocs;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&me);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);

int N = 10;

for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
   //(1)do some stuff in parallel...
   //(2)gather results and write an input file for executable

   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   //(3)run executable in parallel.
   // which is usually run from command line as:
   // 
   // mpirun -np 6 external.exe < input.file
   //
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   //(4)gather output from executable, distribute info among processors and keep running 
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

it's the (3) where i have a problem understanding how to do it and tell how many processors can it use. My confusion is also that some kind of "run" command should probably be executed from a single processor/instance. So how do i make it work and let **parallel executable use all processors** which were provided to the main program? If it is possible.

p/s/ i saw similar questions here in stackoverflow, but no definite answer on if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have control over the exe, i.e. can you change its code? If so, I'd suggest re-developing it so that the exe is simply a wrapper around the behavior you need, and then you can link in the actual action into your application.

If that is not an option, I suggest just calling the executable from your master (rank 0) process, and let the others wait. Not super efficient, but it'll do the job:

```
if (me == 0) {
    system("mpirun -np 6 external.exe < input.file")
}
```

You'll have to figure out a way to wait until the command is finished, but according to the docs of [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) and [mpirun](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun) it should be as simple as checking if the return value from `system(...)` is zero, and then continue (after a barrier, as in your example).

Comment: the question is, will the external executable be able to use those 6 processors? Will there be any collapse between his MPI_Init and the one called in the main program? Or is it completely safe to execute "mpirun" from a single instance?

Comment: @Denis: Quoting from the [`mpirun` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun): *"mpirun" is a shell script that attempts to hide the differences in starting jobs for various devices from the user*. Given that, I assume it would be OK.

If you're uncertain, I'd recommend writing a small tryout exe and see for yourself. If you run into problem, start by creating a new communicator for the main program, so as not to conflict with the communicator used in the external exe (if that would ever be a problem - I don't know the details of `MPI_Initialize` etc).

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'll try to check it in a small program and mark the answer if it works...