# Calling a mpi program within a mpi program

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, gfortran

Let us assume, I have 2 mpi programs with 2 of their executables. I wish to call another program within a program.
I went through few solutions but didn't work for me. For example: [parallel run of executable within MPI in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678943/parallel-run-of-executable-within-mpi-in-c)
.Let the main program be F1.f90 which looks like:

```
program main
implicit none
include 'mpif.h'
integer i,ni,nj,images,ierr,mpisize,mpirank

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,mpisize,ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,mpirank,ierr)

if(mpirank .eq. 0) then
    print*, 'START'
endif

if(mpirank .eq. 0) then
    print*,'Going in hallo'
    call system ('./run2')
endif

if(mpirank .eq. 0) then
    print*, 'END'
endif

call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

where run2 is:

```
mpirun -np 2 ./hallo.exe
```

The second program looks like:

```
PROGRAM hello_world_mpi
include 'mpif.h'

integer process_Rank, size_Of_Cluster, ierror, tag

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror)

print *, 'Hello World from process: ', process_Rank, 'of ', size_Of_Cluster

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
END PROGRAM
```

Then, I wish to run the main program by:

```
mpirun -np 2 ./F1.exe
```

But when I tried to run the program I received the following:

```
 START
 Going in hallo


**********************************************************

Open MPI does not support recursive calls of mpirun

**********************************************************
 END
```

I am not from computer science or IT. Is there any simple solution to run this kind of code, where we call a mpi program within a mpi program?
Thank you.

Comment: TL;DR you cannot
that being said, you have at least two options:
`mpirun -np 1 ./F1.exe : -np 2 ./hallo.exe`
or
`mpirun -np 1 ./F1.exe` and then `MPI_Comm_spawn(..., ./hallo.exe)`.
the second option might be harder since you will get an intercommunicator and you will need to `MPI_Comm_disconnect()` to properly terminate your program.

Comment: Hi! @GillesGouaillardet. Thanks a lot for your answer. I explored a bit about the two options. The first one seems easy. But as I was testing I think hallo.exe is executed in the beginning than F1.exe. Am I correct?

Comment: they run at the same time, `F1.exe` has rank `0` and `hallo.exe` has ranks `1-2`